# How to flag the last row of a data frame group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lead

Suppose we start with the below dataframe `df`:

```
 ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
 Period <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
 Value <- c(10,12,11,4,6)
 df <- data.frame(ID, Period, Value)

      ID Period Value
    1  1      1    10
    2  1      2    12
    3  1      3    11
    4  5      1     4
    5  5      2     6
```

Now using dplyr I add a "Calculate" column that multiplies Period and Value of each row, giving me the following:

```
> df %>% mutate(Calculate = Period * Value)

  ID Period Value Calculate
1  1      1    10        10
2  1      2    12        24
3  1      3    11        33
4  5      1     4         4
5  5      2     6        12
```

I'd like to modify the above "Calculate" to give me a value of 0, when reaching the last row for a given ID, so that the data frame output looks like:

```
  ID Period Value Calculate
1  1      1    10        10
2  1      2    12        24
3  1      3    11         0
4  5      1     4         4
5  5      2     6         0
```

I was going to use the `lead()` function to peer at the next row to see if the ID changes but wasn't sure that happens when reaching the end of the data frame.

How could this be accomplished using dplyr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group_by` `ID` and replace the last row for each `ID` with 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Period * Value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Calculate = replace(Calculate, n(), 0)) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID Period Value Calculate
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1      1    10        10
#2     1      2    12        24
#3     1      3    11         0
#4     5      1     4         4
#5     5      2     6         0
```

Comment: You're always so helpful Ronak! :)

Comment: I agree, Ronak is amazingly helpful. This Ronak solution is clean and clear, now I see n( ) refers to the last row in a group. That is very helpful for me and others to learn (and remember)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
Period <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
Value <- c(10,12,11,4,6)
df <- data.frame(ID, Period, Value)

df %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Period * Value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = if_else(row_number() == n(), 0, Calculate)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>      ID Period Value Calculate
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1      1    10        10
#> 2     1      2    12        24
#> 3     1      3    11         0
#> 4     5      1     4         4
#> 5     5      2     6         0
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
Period <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
Value <- c(10,12,11,4,6)
df <- data.frame(ID, Period, Value)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Period * Value * duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE)) 
#>   ID Period Value Calculate
#> 1  1      1    10        10
#> 2  1      2    12        24
#> 3  1      3    11         0
#> 4  5      1     4         4
#> 5  5      2     6         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can also replace rownum with Period (most likely)

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
Period <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
Value <- c(10,12,11,4,6)
df <- data.frame(ID, Period, Value)

df = df %>% mutate(Calculate = Period * Value)
df$rownum = rownames(df)

df = df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Calculate = ifelse(rownum == max(rownum), 0, Calculate)) %>%
  ungroup()

 A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID Period Value Calculate rownum
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
1     1      1    10        10 1     
2     1      2    12        24 2     
3     1      3    11         0 3     
4     5      1     4         4 4     
5     5      2     6         0 5
```